# how to empty a directory in c# xaml metro style?

Tags: c#, xaml

i have this c# code and i want to delete a certain sub directory in Documents Library. However this produces an error because the directory is not empty. I hope someone can guide me on how to do this.

thank you for any prompt reply.

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;              
var queryResult = storageFolder.CreateFolderQuery();
IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> folderList = await queryResult.GetFoldersAsync();

 foreach (StorageFolder folder in folderList)
    {
       await folder.DeleteAsync();             
    }
```

Comment: You must delete all the files in the folders that you are trying to delete. You can only delete an empty directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync()` to obtain a list of all the files present in the folders and delete them prior to deleting the folders since there is no way in the `DeleteAsync()` method to specify subfolders and files.

More info: [StorageFolder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR227230) | MSDN

Answer (score 2):

Hope this may help.

```
 public async void deletefile()
        {
            StorageFolder sourceFolder =  ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
           // sourceFolder = await sourceFolder.GetFolderAsync("Test");
           // await sourceFolder.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);


          // var files = await sourceFolder.GetFilesAsync();

           IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> folderList = await sourceFolder.GetFilesAsync();
            if (folderList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (StorageFile f1 in folderList)
                {

                    await f1.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);
                }
            }

           //StorageFile retfile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.GetFileAsync("MysoundFile.mp3");
           // if (retfile != null)
           // {
           //     await retfile.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);
           // }


        }
```